# GET Request not Getting Saved When Requesting Session Variable in View-- Django

Tags: django, get, django-forms, django-views

When I navigate to my first view, the GET request is saved as a session variable.

```
def index(request):

if request.method == 'GET':
    symbol = request.GET.get('symbol', 'none')
    request.session['symbol'] = symbol

return render(request, 'backtests/yieldcurve.html', {'symbol' : symbol})
```

Then, when I navigate to another page via the sidebar, the GET request still shows up.

```
def yieldcurve(request):

    symbol = request.session.get('symbol', 'none')

    return render(request, 'backtests/yieldcurve.html', {'symbol' : symbol})
```

Yet, when I navigate back to the index from the sidebar, the GET request is not saved. Is there a way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Two quick things: First, there's no indentation in your second block of code which would throw an error if it's not just a StackOverflow copy/paste formatting issue. Second, what specifically do you mean by "saved?"

Comment: Thanks, it was just a copy/paste error. I mean I am trying to get the session variable I had set, but when I navigate back to index it runs through the if again and it sets a new session variable to none if I am understanding correctly. How would I get the session variable even when I return to the index? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out...

```
def index(request):

    if 'symbol' in request.GET:
        symbol = request.GET.get('symbol','Invalid Symbol')
        request.session['symbol'] = symbol
    else:
        symbol = request.session['symbol']
```

Answer (score 0):

Because whenever you go to index with a GET, you always overwrite whatever's saved in the session. If you have nothing in the GET request, you overwrite the session value with `none`.

You should probably check that the symbol is in `request.GET` and not in `request.session` before setting it.

Comment: Hey Daniel I am still a little confused. You are saying that in my index I need to add something that sees if there is a symbol in the GET request?

Comment: Yes, why is that confusing? If you don't have one, then you overwrite what's in the session with the string "none".

Comment: Im sorry but can you please give me an example? I know it may seem very basic to you.

Comment: if 'symbol' in request.GET:
        symbol = request.GET.get('symbol', 'none')

    
    
    elif 'symbol' not in request.GET:
        
        request.session['symbol'] = symbol